# Webpack adding jQuery plugin: Error: jQuery requires a window with a document

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-webpack-starter

I'm using Angular 4 +webpack.I've added a jQuery plugin to nonTreeShakableModules const in  webpack.config.vendor.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');

const treeShakableModules = [
    '@angular/animations',
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
    'zone.js',

];
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'bootstrap',
    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
    'es6-promise',
    'es6-shim',
    'event-source-polyfill',
    'jquery',
    'virtual-keyboard'              //HERE
];
```

When starting the application I got this error:

> NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error:
>   **jQuery requires a window with a document**

If I refresh the page for 2-3 times,error is gone.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to be able to use jquery in your application?

Comment: Hi.I want to use Mottie Virtual keryboard jquey plugin in an Angular 4 +webapck application.Jquery is incuded and seems to be working.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47022010/asp-core-angular-4-vs-2017-moving-from-webpack-template-to-something-else), you can't run javascript code which depends on `window` and some other cases (like session storage) on the server-side with server-sided pre-rendering.

Templates such as ASP.NET Core Angular Web templates comes with server-sided rendering **enabled**. This works fine for applications which doesn't require session storage, authentication or access to browser components or dom-tree.

You have to **disable** server-sided prerendering by removing the `asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/app.module.server.ts"` tag helper from your `Index.cshtml`.

Replace

```
<my-app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/app.module.server.ts"></my-app>
```

with

```
<my-app></my-app>
```

Of course replace `my-app` with the selector of your application, typically `app` in templates.

Alternatively you have to run code conditionally, as pointed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/609#issuecomment-275497988):

```
// boot-client.ts file 
import 'ngx-charts';

// some.component.ts
import { isBrowser } from 'angular2-universal';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

// inside ngOnInit 
if (isBrowser) { 
    $('body').hide();  // or whatever call you need to make
}
```

to avoid running such code on the server-sided pre-rendering.

Comment: for the moment the error has gone.i'll keep testing.thanks