# Side-server pre-rendering does not work with http requests

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, server-side-rendering

I have set up an `Angular SPA with Visual Studio 2017` which enables server-side pre-rendering. However, I discovered my app does not run if I add an Http request. **Notice that, if there is no Http request or I disabled pre-rendering and keep Http request everything is fine**. Here some parts of my code are following:

index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>

<script src="~/dist/vendor.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/main-client.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

startup.cs

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
```

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.6",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "preboot": "^5.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.20.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3"
  }
}
```

get-info.service.js

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class GetCustomerInfoService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getResults() {
        return this.http.get('api/test');
    }
}
```

test.component.ts

```
constructor(private customerInfo: GetInfoService) {
        this.customerInfo.getResults().subscribe(result => {
            console.log(result);
        });

    }
```

The error I am getting:

*An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. NodeInvocationException: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined*

Any idea to fix the above issue?

Comment: what's in your Startup.cs

Comment: I just added it

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241293/angular-2-and-mvc-routing

Comment: You seem to be trying to execute XmlHttpRequest on the server side. Make sure that that the code that uses XmlHttpRequest runs on the client. Here is a similar case: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1088#issuecomment-342475258